# How to Get SelectedItem as DataTemplate in Listview?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, datatemplate

I have a listview Which is defined as follows:

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="myTemplate" x:DataType="table:myItem">
  <RichTextBlock Margin="10" IsTextSelectionEnabled="False">
    <Paragraph x:Name="txtParagraph">
      ....
    </Paragraph>
  </RichTextBlock>
</DataTemplate>

<ListView name="lst" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myTemplate}"/>

lst.ItemSource = someData;
```

Now I want to get paragraph from the DataTemplate of the current item
something like this:

```
paragraph = GetParagraphFromItem(listview.selectedItem)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: This is already solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21111594/select-object-in-listview-using-selected-datatemplate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to Get SelectedItem as DataTemplate in Listview?

You could get each `ListViewItem` with [`ContainerFromItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemcontainergenerator.containerfromitem?view=winrt-22621) method and then you could access item's `ContentTemplateRoot` property to get `RichTextBlock`. And Paragraph was stored in RichTextBlock's Blocks collection.

```
 var listviewItem = MyListView.ContainerFromItem(yourselecteditem) as ListViewItem;
 RichTextBlock rtb = listviewItem.ContentTemplateRoot as RichTextBlock;
 var txtParagraph = rtb.Blocks.Where(p => p.Name == "txtParagraph").FirstOrDefault();
```